# Chart.js Show label/tooltip for single point when multiple points coincide

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a Chart.js scatter plot where data points from two different datasets occasionally coincide/overlap. They have the same x and y coordinate. On default, when the points are hovered, the tooltip shows info for both data points. My desired behavior is to get the information for the first overlapping point only. I can achieve this using tooltips' mode set to 'single'.

```
var config = {
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            mode: "single"
        }
    }
}
```

Although this works fine, my question/problem arises because chart.js' documentation states that mode 'single' is [deprecated](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#single-deprecated). It suggests using mode 'nearest' with intersect set to 'true' would achieve the same result, however [it doesn't](https://jsfiddle.net/f5epdn2w/).

Below is a reproduction of the issue:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas></canvas>
</body>
<script>
var config = {
        type: "scatter",
        data: {
            labels: ["label1", "label2"],
            datasets: [{label: "label1", data:[{x: 1, y:1},{x: 2, y:2},{x: 3, y:3},{x: 4, y:4},{x: 5, y:2}], backgroundColor: "rgb(155,0,0)"},{label: "label2", data:[{x: 1, y:1},{x: 2, y:4},{x: 3, y:3},{x: 4, y:6},{x: 5, y:8}], backgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,155)"}]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    type: "linear",
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: "labels",
                        fontStyle: "bold"
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        autoSkip: true,
                        maxTicksLimit: 7
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    type: "linear",
                    beginAtZero: true
                }]
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: "nearest",
                intersect: true
            }
        }
    }
    var chart = new Chart(document.querySelector("canvas"), config);
</script>
</html>
```

And here is the desired behavior with the deprecated 'single' argument:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas></canvas>
</body>
<script>
var config = {
        type: "scatter",
        data: {
            labels: ["label1", "label2"],
            datasets: [{label: "label1", data:[{x: 1, y:1},{x: 2, y:2},{x: 3, y:3},{x: 4, y:4},{x: 5, y:2}], backgroundColor: "rgb(155,0,0)"},{label: "label2", data:[{x: 1, y:1},{x: 2, y:4},{x: 3, y:3},{x: 4, y:6},{x: 5, y:8}], backgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,155)"}]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    type: "linear",
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: "labels",
                        fontStyle: "bold"
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        autoSkip: true,
                        maxTicksLimit: 7
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    type: "linear",
                    beginAtZero: true
                }]
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: "single"
            }
        }
    }
    var chart = new Chart(document.querySelector("canvas"), config);
</script>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? Especially for people who might run into this issue if/when 'single' is removed. Thank you, cheers.

Comment: Did you find a solution to display a single point @Lorne ? I am encountering the exact same issue...

Comment: Still using 'single' as no solution was proposed. I have downloaded and uploaded a copy of a working version of the chart.js file, so there is no risk of it getting 'deprecated' in my case. If you need a working copy of the file I can provide it, as the website seems to have updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `afterBody` callback to manually adjust what the tooltip is going to show by removing all but the one point that you want to show. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

You can filter tooltips using knowledge about the entire dataset

```
// ChartJs version: 3.7.1

tooltip: {
  filter: (item, index, list) => (
    item.parsed.x !== list[0].parsed.x &&
    item.parsed.y !== list[0].parsed.y) ||
    index === 0
  )
}

// ...
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkioz.png)